# Importing IceFaces crashes the webapplication

Tags: jsf, icefaces

I would like to work with icefaces, but as soon as I import the libraries of icefaces, my webapplication crashes after clicking a button on the form which worked properly before the import.

What could go wrong?

[image]

The source Java:

```
package test,

import javax.faces.bean.ManagedBean;

@ManagedBean
public class Student {

private String firstName;

// create no-arg constructor
public Student() {

}

// define getter/setter methods 
public String getFirstName() {
    return firstName;
}

public void setFirstName(String firstName) {
    this.firstName = firstName;
}

}
```

index.xhtml:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en"
  xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
  xmlns:h="http://xmlns.jcp.org/jsf/html">
<h:head>
    <title>Student Registration Form</title>
</h:head>
<h:body>
    <h:form>
        First name: <h:inputText value="#{student.firstName}" />        
        <br/><br/>
        <h:commandButton value="Submit" action="student_response" />
    </h:form>
</h:body>
```

student_response.xhtml

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en"
xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
xmlns:h="http://xmlns.jcp.org/jsf/html">
<h:head>
    <title>Student Confirmation</title>
</h:head>

<h:body>

    The student is confirmed: #{student.firstName} 

</h:body>
</html>
```

The error I get:
[image]

Comment: Where did you get the IceFaces bundle? You are duplicating APIs like `javax.faces`, `javax.servlet`, `javax.annotation`.

Comment: Indeed, the runtime classpath is a mess. It looks like JARs are thrown in arbitrarily. Get rid of duplicate and container-prodiced JARs from WAR.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you have 2 javax.faces. jars in classpath according to your first screenshot.

Please remove ONE of the faces jars in your classpath.

Comment: Can you add a link where it is confirmed that IceFaces has its own faces servlet implementation and that mojarra or MyFaces is not needed.

Comment: You did a bad job in explaining the cause of the problem. Please edit and improve, this is misleading to future readers.